# Hive - Sum of related values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, count, presto, amazon-athena

Im working on AWS Athena to filter Load balancer logs. I have created the below table and imported the logs into the table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elb_logs  (
  request_timestamp string,   
  elb_response_code string,    
  url string, 
   ) 

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
         'serialization.format' = '1','input.regex' = '([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:\-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \\\"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\\\" (\"[^\"]*\") ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*)$' )
LOCATION 's3://athena-examples/elb/raw/';
```

Now I want to get the *count of 200 OK, 400 and 500 responses count*. So I executed the below query.

```
SELECT distinct(elb_response_code),
         count(url) AS count
FROM elb_logs
GROUP BY  elb_response_code
```

It worked but it returns all responses, like below.

```
**response  count**
401   1270
201   1369
422   342
200   3568727
400   1221
404   444
304   10435
413   3
206   30
500   1542
```

I want to sum all 400,401,404,413,422 and the same thing for 2xx, 3xx and 5xx So the result should be 4xx   sum(400,401,404,413,422)

```
**response  count**
4xx           52145  
2xx           1363224
5xx           532
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all codes are 3 characters long

```
select      substr (elb_response_code,1,1) || 'xx' as elb_response_code_prefix
           ,count(*)                               as cnt

from        elb_logs

group by    1
```

And here is more generic solution

```
select      rpad (substr (elb_response_code,1,1),length(elb_response_code),'x') 
                      as elb_response_code_prefix
           ,count(*)  as cnt

from        elb_logs

group by    1
```

Comment: Thanks, its working, Is this possible to show the response code value with xx. like 2xx, 3xx in the result window? Right now its showing 2,3,4,5.

Comment: You're welcome. P.s. see updated solution. There are many variations for this.